# Редирект в Middleware.ts Next 14.1

Tags: reactjs, nextjs, middleware

Подскажите как сделать редирект в middleware.ts (Next 14.1) по условию: При переходе на страницу админ панели, проверяем является ли пользователь админом, если нет делаем редирект на 404 страницу. Весь код отрабатывает, кроме  перехода на 404. Как правильно реализовать данный редирект в middleware?

```html
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { ADMIN_URL, PUBLIC_URL } from './configs/url.config'
import { EnumTokens } from './configs/enum.tokens'

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

        const accessToken = request.cookies.get(EnumTokens.ACCESS_TOKEN)?.value

    //Если перешел на админ панель проверяем является ли админом, если нет делаем редирект на 404 страницу:
    if (request.nextUrl.pathname === ADMIN_URL.homeUrl()) {
        fetch('http://11.111.111.111:4200/api/users/profile', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` }
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => !data.isAdmin ? NextResponse.error() : null)
    }

    return
}

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/profile/:path*', '/admin/:path*']
}
```

Comment: нужно поставить `await` перед fetch

Comment: не помогает, ничего не меняется. Строка .then((data) => !data.isAdmin ? NextResponse.error() : null) игнорируется. Если законсолить .then((data) => console.log(data.isAdmin)) приходит false.

Comment: а откуда ты взял `NextResponse.error()`?

Comment: Тут суть не в NextResponse.error(), вместо него можем взять например NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/dashboard/user', request.url)), он также не сработает. Любой редирект не срабатывает.  Строка просто игнорируется.

Comment: потому что его нужно вернуть. добавь еще return перед await